# how to extract numbers in regex followed by multiple conditions

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
"these 13 keys are 4, C1, C2, 11, 12, 26, 54, 70, 75, 80, 87, 89 and 95 some other 2 text"
```

and i'm trying, using Regex, to extract the keys. 
there are several conditions in order the key to be valid:

- the numbers needs to be **after** the word `are`
- the last number ends with prefix of `and`

so the results should be:

`4` `C1` `C2` `11` `12` `26` `54` `70` `75` `80` `87` `89` `95`

the numbers `13` and `2` shouldn't returns as key result.

I used `(?= )[^,]+` but the first and last results are incorrect (getting `13 keys are 4` and `and 95 some other text`) as results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative:

```
(\w+(?=,)|(?<=and\s)\w+)
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/gQ0xC9/5)

Explaining:

```
(                   # start of matching group
    \w+             # a key
    (?=,)           # followed by a comma - without taking it
  |                 # or
    (?<=and\s)      # preceded by "and " - without taking it
    \w+             # a key
)                   # end of matching group
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks good doesn't it. Do you actually [need the capture group?](https://regex101.com/r/qO9dT9/2)

Comment: Sorry @WashingtonGuedes but it doesn't works. (I had a mistake in the string.) the number `89` is not in the result

Answer (score 2):

You could use this expression to extract the first piece: `are (([\d, A-Z]+) and \d+)`. This will yield the following string: `4, C1, C2, 11, 12, 26, 54, 70, 75, 80, 87, 89, and 95` as a regex group.

Secondly, you could simply do `split(\s*(,|and)\s*)` this should in turn, yield the values which are separated by `,`, or in case of the last one, by the `and` text.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
(?<=are\s|and\s|,\s)[A-Z0-9]{1,2}
```

where:

- `(?<=are\s|and\s|,\s)` - lookbehind, the rest of regex is preceded by:
  "are", "and" or "," with whitespace character;
- `[A-Z0-9]{1,2}` - one or two (like in example) decimals or letters (this part depend on what keys exactly are allowed, it could be also replaced with for example `\w\d` - one letter or decimal, and decimal or with `\w{1,2}` two word characters (A-Za-z0-9_))

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jT7vQ9/7)

Implementation in Java:

```
public class RegexTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String string = "these 13 keys are 4, C1, C2, 11, 12, 26, 54, 70, 75, 80, 87, 89, and 95 some other 2 text";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=are\\s|and\\s|,\\s)[A-Z0-9]{1,2}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print(string.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end())+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

with result:

> C1 C2 11 12 26 54 70 75 80 87 89 95

Answer (score 0):

```
    String test = "these 13 keys are 4, C1, C2, 11, 12, 26, 54, 70, 75, 80, 87, 89, and 95 some other 2 text";
    String[] t  = test.split("are")[1].split("and")[0].split(",");
String t95 = test.split("are")[1].split("and")[1].split("some")[0];    
for(String st : t){
            System.out.println(st);
    }
```

only a quick dirty solution :)